# Silverlight 5 binding. Find ancestor by name?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

Is there a binding mode in SL5 to bind to an ancestor by name?

Something like:

```
{Binding AParentProp, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindByName="MyParent"}
```

Comment: You can bind to a specific element: `ElementName=`. Can you give more details of what you are trying to do?

Comment: can you give an example please. i am not familiar with elementname. P.S. i want to bind to a particular element which is higher in the visual tree hierarchy..

Comment: It's `{Binding Property, ElementName=name}` but it will only work if you have a uniquely named element. If you have a list (say) and want to bind to a property of a list element I don't think it will work.

Comment: put this as an answer pls. i'll mark it... Chris, this is tautology - of course an element name is a unique string or compiler will throw it out of the window... ja?

Comment: not necessarily. You can name items within DataTemplates that get reused in lists etc.

Comment: you are right.. i never thought about it this way. cheers ;)

Comment: It's something I'm experimenting with at the moment, so I don't have anything concrete as to how it's handled.

Comment: forget it. thanks for the tip though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to a specific named element like this:

```
{Binding Property, ElementName=name}
```

You name your elements like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="name" ....>

</Grid>
```